# CentOS - how to look for dropped connections from NIC

Tags: centos, sendmail, web

I'm running CentOS 5 and sendmail. Sendmail serves as an MTA for a webserver on the same LAN segment. Most emails go through, but I do get several errors in /var/log/maillog that read:

```
Oct 20 11:10:01 mail sendmail[15733]: s9K29kgh015733: <webserver> [<ip redacted>] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
```

It looks like connections between the MTA and the webserver occasionally get dropped while the webserver is attempting to create emails, so we get these errors and customers never get the email.

How can I monitor the NIC on the Linux server running sendmail so I can see what is terminating the connection?

Comment: I assume that this is already answered by now but for others that may come across this issue, some helpful information to know would be: 1) is there a pattern to the disconnects? 2) What is the mail component on the upstream server that is initiating the connection? 3) is there any intermediary network devices in between? For example, IPS, IDS, firewall performing deep packet inspection, etc.

Comment: @MikeB, to answer your questions; 1) No, nothing apparent. The times, dates are different. There aren't any scheduled jobs or reboots or anything that seemingly would cause the problem. 2) It's a custom program and it works most of the time. 3) Both servers are on the same switch (Cisco 2960 but I have no access to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue with NIC?

You can use the ip_route2 tool `ip` to display the statistics about a particular network interface.

```
$ ip -s link show wlp1s0
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:f7:33:15:0b:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    2080111115 7611725  0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    727520431  6328004  0       0       0       0
```

The above shows packets received (RX) and sent (TX) along with any errors that occurred as packets traveled in/out of the NIC. You can see all the interfaces like this:

```
$ ip -s link
```

Similar commands such as `ifconfig` and `netstat -i` will report the same type of info.

#### Issue with connection?

If the NIC seems fine otherwise, then I'd diagnose the issue higher up the foodc chain. For that you can use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to monitor the respective interface, right down to specific ports and specific IP addresses.

**NOTE:** There are many example commands for `tcpdump` available here: [Tcpdump usage examples](http://www.rationallyparanoid.com/articles/tcpdump.html).

In your case something like this will help to capture the network traffic between your host and the webserver. On the CentOS system:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n "src host 192.168.1.1 and dst port 25"
```

Where the IP above would be the server attempting to connect to the CentOS system. The port, 25, is typically used for SMTP.

#### Moving up even higher?

I would suspect that your real issue is not down below, but is likely the mail server dropping the mail for some reason. Perhaps it's malformed or is missing header info. I would suggest turning up the logging of the mail server, assuming it's `sendmail`, you could do something like this in the configuration file, `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`. You'll need to restart `sendmail` afterwards:

```
O LogLevel=9
```

Comment: thanks, that's a lot of great info. It is `sendmail` on the MTA, so I can up the log level and see what we get. Do I need to recompile sendmail or just restart it?

Comment: @Tensigh - just a restart should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.